# Can I test react-native-iap without having an app in production in the apple store?

Tags: javascript, react-native, in-app-purchase

I need to implement iap in my app because it was rejected by the app because there are external purchases. Anyway, I'm trying to implement react-native-iap, however I have questions about how to do this.

Does the app need to be in production?

I have developer account available ..

I add, 3 products in my app on apple connect:

```js
test_1  Non-Consumable  20  Ready to Submit
test_2  Consumable      2   Ready to Submit
test_3  Non-Consumable  1   Ready to Submit
```

And i try test example from this lib, but I can not bring the products listed there.

```js
const itemSkus = Platform.select({
    ios: [
      'test_1', 'test_2', 'test_3'
    ],
    android: [
      'android.test.purchased',
    ],
  });

[ ... ]

getItems = async() => {
        try {
          const products = await RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus);
          // const products = await RNIap.getSubscriptions(itemSkus);
          console.log('Products', products);
          this.setState({ productList: products });
        } catch (err) {
          console.warn(err.code, err.message);
        }
}
```

I would like to know how to integrate with my app for testing.!!

Comment: You only need follow this steps. I followed it and i didn't have any problem. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Comment: I did these steps, however the list comes empty when capturing these products in the app, I do not know what it can be :(

Comment: Make sure  you add at least on Localization in the App Store Information for your in app purchases on iTunesConnect.

Comment: Are you solve it?